# Replace the filename in the URI using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In my website, the main PHP script is named `index.php`. All URIs look similar to this:

> index.php?section=FrontPage&l=ES_LA&view=multiple

In the [`htaccess`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html) file and using the [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) extension, I managed to remove the `.php` PHP extension, so the URI looks like this:

> index?section=FrontPage&l=ES_LA&view=multiple

What I want to do now is to replace `index.php` with `example` in the path.

I've tried using:

```
RewriteRule ^example$ index.php
```

But when I try accessing `example?section=FrontPage&l=ES_LA&view=multiple` the server returns a [404 Not Found status code](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.4.5).

How can I fix this?

Comment: The `index.php` is optional in most servers. Why not use a url like `http://example.com/?section=FrontPage&l=ES_LA&view=multiple`. Should work right of the box.

Comment: Yes, ¿what's the purpose of `example` instead of `index.php` ¿Why not just the query string `/?section=...` as `Gerben` suggested?

Comment: I finally ended up using `RewriteRule ^example(.+)$ index.php$1` and it worked.